# Backbone Model URL responseText

Tags: json, url, backbone.js, collections

I have the following:

```
DiaryEntries.Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '/rest/diary/'
});
```

So I initiate a collection like so:

```
var collection = new DiaryEntries.Collection()
```

And then `collection.fetch()` returns this:

```
Object {readyState: 1, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}
abort: function ( statusText ) {
always: function () {
complete: function () {
done: function () {
error: function () {
fail: function () {
getAllResponseHeaders: function () {
getResponseHeader: function ( key ) {
overrideMimeType: function ( type ) {
pipe: function ( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress */ ) {
progress: function () {
promise: function ( obj ) {
readyState: 4
responseJSON: Array[1]
responseText: "[{"DEID":"1","DEOwnerID":"1","DEClientID":null,"DEDateStart":"2013-06-28 00:00:00","DEDateEnd":"2013-06-29 00:00:00","DEEventLocationID":null,"DEJobID":null,"DEName":"Ricky's test event","DELocation":"Kettering","DEFurtherDetails":"None","DEVisibility":"0","DENotes":"None","DEType":"1"}]"
setRequestHeader: function ( name, value ) {
state: function () {
status: 200
statusCode: function ( map ) {
statusText: "OK"
success: function () {
then: function ( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress */ ) {
__proto__: Object
```

Why is it not just getting the response? I have a mime type of `application/json`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call to the server are AJAX calls (**asynchronous**). What `fetch` returns is the XHR object, not the response (as the server hasn't responded yet). To do something once the client received the data, use a callback or a listener (or something similar).

For example, you can declare a `parse` method to see the reponse (it's not the actual goal of the method, but whatever):

```
DiaryEntries.Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: '/rest/diary/',
  parse: function(response) {console.log(response); return response;}
});
```

Comment: Ok cheers. I have the parse function in  the model and console logging works well. So I use: 

`parse : function(response) {
  self.entries = response;
 }` yet when I call `diary.entries`, the result looks like this: `_byId: Object
length: 0
models: Array[0]`

Comment: (`self` being declared as `this`)

Comment: @rickyduck using `parse` was only for the purpose of showing you response. You don't have to do anything, the collection will populate itself (in your example your parse method returns nothing, so your collection is empty).

Comment: Maybe try to use the `success` and `error` callback to see what's happening as well (pass them as options when you fetch).

Comment: It's ok, I've worked it out now. Thanks for your help, the code you gave me worked :)